# How to improve Beautiful soup webscrape loop?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm dipping my toes into webscraping with beautiful soup, and to do so I'm doing a small project where I'm looking at a pokemon fansite and getting the pokemon moves from a table. I'm going for the move name and nothing else. Currently my code does that poorly and incorrectly until the very bottom of its output.
It looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMKV5.png).

It eventually does what I anticipate at the end there (starting with pound).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYNwS.png) is what the table looks like on the webpage.

What I've got:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# Load page
r = requests.get("https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_moves")

# Convert to soup object
soup = bs(r.content)

# Get first table (aka the one we need)
first_table = soup.find('table')

# Loop and grab what we want
for td in first_table.find_all('td', style=False, align=False):
    download = td.find_all('a', href=True, title=True, style=False, align=False)
    for a in download:
        text = a.string
        print(text)
input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is not even necessary. You can simply use `pandas` to scrape the entire table:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_moves")

df = pd.read_html(r.content)[1]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       #             Name      Type  Category Contest  PP Power Accuracy   Gen
0      1            Pound    Normal  Physical   Tough  35    40     100%     I
1      2     Karate Chop*  Fighting  Physical   Tough  25    50     100%     I
2      3      Double Slap    Normal  Physical    Cute  10    15      85%     I
3      4      Comet Punch    Normal  Physical   Tough  15    18      85%     I
4      5       Mega Punch    Normal  Physical   Tough  20    80      85%     I
..   ...              ...       ...       ...     ...  ..   ...      ...   ...
821  822      Fiery Wrath      Dark   Special     ???  10    90     100%  VIII
822  823  Thunderous Kick  Fighting  Physical     ???  10    90     100%  VIII
823  824    Glacial Lance       Ice  Physical     ???   5   130     100%  VIII
824  825   Astral Barrage     Ghost   Special     ???   5   120     100%  VIII
825  826      Eerie Spell   Psychic   Special     ???   5    80     100%  VIII

[826 rows x 9 columns]
```

You can also send these values to a neat `csv` file by adding this line to your code:

```
df.to_csv('Moves.csv', index = False)
```

Screenshot of `csv` file:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you